# Nginx redirects .well-known endpoints

Tags: nginx, web-applications, request, openid-connect, endpoint

I have a web application that runs on `WSGI` server. The application has OpenID Connect identity provider endpoints, for instance:

```
/oidc/.well-known/openid-configuration
/oidc/.well-known/simple-web-discovery
/oidc/.well-known/webfinger
```

Requests to these endpoints are mapped to some functions in my project, which run necessary tasks for each endpoint. I can run my application, and all requests are successfully mapped and handled by the defined functions.

The challenge starts when I host my application on a public IP behind https. For this I use `nginx` to proxy access to my application. `nginx` makes my application accessible over a public IP over https. Here is key sections of my `nginx` config file:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  localhost;
    root         /home/user/myApp;
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://my_app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-URL-SCHEME https;
    }
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;
    root         /home/user/myApp;
    ssl_certificate /home/user/cacert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/user/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    location ~ /\.well-known { allow all; }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://my_app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-URL-SCHEME https;
    }
}
```

Every call is requested/posted correctly, except for the requests to `/.well-known/*` (actually `location ~ /\.well-known { allow all; }` in the config is an attempt to solve it), for which I get either `404` or `403` errors.

For instance, one error message in `nginx` error log reads:

`open() "/home/user/myApp/oidc/.well-known/openid-configuration" failed (13: Permission denied), client: X.X.X.X, server: localhost, request: "GET /oidc/.well-known/openid-configuration HTTP/1.1", host: "X.X.X.X"`

(IP addresses are masked out)

Few points:

- I'm running my application with `sudo` privileges, so the application has r/w access to all the paths.
- Actually, the path `/home/user/myApp/oidc/.well-known/openid-configuration` does not exist (and thats why I also get `404` error).

`/oidc/.well-known/openid-configuration` should be mapped to a function (as it happens when I host my application without `nginx`). So, I don't understand why `nginx` tries to access a non-existing `/oidc/.well-known/*` path/file ?!

Comment: The `location ~ /\.well-known` make `nginx` look for a local file. Not sure why you added it. What happened before you added that location block?

Comment: I was getting the same errors (404/403); that line is added based on descriptions here: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/404-on-well-known-acme-challenge/15565/9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the setting `location ~ /\.well-known { allow all; }`.

This should be removed. Additionally, the setting `include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;` includes a default config file which also has the setting `location ~ /\.well-known { allow all; }`. This setting should be removed from that file too.